# How to use google API to make a video call from hangouts directly to another email

Tags: hangouts-api

I would like to integrate a video call feature on my website.
If I integrate the following code:

I am able to invoke hangouts. But this requires users to type in the email ID of the people they would like to make a video call.

How can I automate this manual step? Is there a way to pass the email Id to the above code, so it automatically calls the other person.

Thank you

Comment: Where is the code?  how can you just invoke hangouts?

Answer (score 0):

As of Now, this is not possible. Hangouts Chat API is only used to create chatbots and you could start a conversation with a specific user.